# WCSession has not been activated

Tags: swift

I get the WCSession has not been activated error when I try to sent something. And I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have tested serval pre-made solutions what "must" work. But it doesn't work at my simulator and physical devices.

Some code:

My app delegate:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import WatchConnectivity


@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, WCSessionDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func session(session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : AnyObject], replyHandler: ([String : String]) -> Void) {
        replyHandler(["message": "Hello Watch!"])
    }

    func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
    }

    func sessionDidBecomeInactive(_ session: WCSession) {

    }

    func sessionDidDeactivate(_ session: WCSession) {

    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        if WCSession.isSupported() {
            let session = WCSession.default()
            session.delegate = self
            session.activate()
        }

        return true
    }

........


}
```

My interfaceController:

```
import WatchKit
import Foundation
import WatchConnectivity


class InterfaceController: WKInterfaceController {


    override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
        super.awake(withContext: context)

        // Configure interface objects here.
    }

    override func willActivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
        super.willActivate()

        if WCSession.default().isReachable {
            let messageDict = ["message": "hello iPhone!"]

            WCSession.default().sendMessage(messageDict, replyHandler: { (replyDict) -> Void in
                //print(replyDict)
            }, errorHandler: { (error) -> Void in
               // print(error)
            })
        }

    }

    func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
    }

    func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any]) {

    }

    override func didDeactivate() {
        // This method is called when watch view controller is no longer visible
        super.didDeactivate()
    }
}
```

The extensionDelegate:

```
   import WatchKit
    import WatchConnectivity

        class ExtensionDelegate: NSObject, WKExtensionDelegate, WCSessionDelegate {

        func applicationDidFinishLaunching() {
            // Perform any final initialization of your application.
            if WCSession.isSupported() {
                let session = WCSession.default()
                session.delegate = self
                session.activate()
            }
        }

        func session(_ session: WCSession, activationDidCompleteWith activationState: WCSessionActivationState, error: Error?) {
        }

        func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any]) {

            }
    ....
```

Is there any wrong code or implementations? Because nothing works for me.

Comment: For me just adding the delegate stubs solved the issue (it worked on Simulator but not on device).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I figured out the problem I had, and I think yours is similar.  I was trying to send a message immediately after calling `activate()`, which worked in the past, but since the introduction of the `session(activationDidCompleteWith:)` function I needed to send my messages from there.

So I think your solution is one of these:

1. Make your InterfaceController be the `WCSessionDelegate`, move all
   `WCSession` activation calls there, and send the message from
   `session(activationDidCompleteWith:)`
2. Send the message from
   `session(activationDidCompleteWith:)` in the `ExtensionDelegate` (in my
   app I handle all communication in the `ExtensionDelegate`)
3. Post a notification from `session(activationDidCompleteWith:)` in the
   `ExtensionDelegate` and add an observer to handle it in
   `InterfaceController`

Aside from this, I think you may also have a problem because the declaration of `session(didReceiveMessage:)` is wrong in your AppDelegate (or at least I had a problem when I tried your code.)

The new declaration is:

```
func session(_ session: WCSession, didReceiveMessage message: [String : Any], replyHandler: @escaping ([String : Any]) -> Void)
```

Answer (score 1):

One other thing to check if your code seems good and the WCsession still will not activate, restart your watch.  This was the answer for me.